# How to hide Services item in QMenubar on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, qt, qt4, menubar

In my Qt4 application I can't seem to hide certain options in the system Menu bar on OS X such as 'Services'. Any ideas?

[image: QMenubar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a feature of the operating system which you don't really have much control over.

Comment: To expand slightly, the "About ..." entry and everything from "Services" on down is standard across nearly every Mac OS X application I know about -- and the only reason I say "nearly" is so I won't be shown wrong if I left it out, and somebody pointed one out to me.

Comment: Thanks, I guess if I'd actually paid attention to other application menus I can see it's in most of them - Skype, Safari, Finder etc.

In Eclipse it's a disabled menu item.

Comment: Eclipse is written in Java, and therefore not a real Mac application.